# Execute remote `HTML code` without 'Redirecting' and staying on the same page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm building a webpage using twitter bootstrap. My goal is show the `modal` when a certain button is clicked.

If I place this 'modal' code in the same file as button, it pops out the modal window 'without' clicking the button, but when I place this modal code in separate file like `file.php` and call it, it redirects to the `file.php` page - which I don't want. I want to be on that button's page.

http://jsfiddle.net/4ZaA3

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Is there any chance you could add some code to your question, or maybe provide an example of the problem on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Otherwise I don't think the community will be able to understand what your problem really is.

Comment: thank you for ur time, here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/4ZaA3/ html section contains 2 separate HTML codes